# Webpack not recognizing css-loader

Tags: reactjs, webpack, css-loader, webpack-loader

My app runs normally with `yarn`, but cannot load the css when I use a benchmarking library `react-benchmark`, which uses webpack. An minimal example of the entire project is here: https://github.com/dustinfreeman/bug-react-benchmark-css-import

Here is the loading error:

```
$ react-benchmark --debug src/index.tsx
✖ Compiling bundle
/Users/dustinfreeman/Documents/Code/bug-react-benchmark-css-import/src/index.css 1:5
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:5)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> body {
|   font: 14px 'Century Gothic', Futura, sans-serif;
|   margin: 20px;
 @ /Users/dustinfreeman/Documents/Code/bug-react-benchmark-css-import/src/index.tsx 3:0-21
 @ ./client.js
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
export const module = {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            importLoaders: 1,
            modules: {
              localIdentName: "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
            },
          }
        }
      ],
      include: /\.module\.css$/
    },
    {
      test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader'
      ],
      exclude: /\.module\.css$/
    },
  ],
};
```

Comment: Looks like that tool doesn't let you use your own webpack config. https://github.com/Rowno/react-benchmark/blob/a06feae2fd72855f345bd2c535a1567ede1e1077/lib/webpack.js

Comment: A possible workaround is to specify the css loader inline. https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#inline

Answer (score 0):

Inline worked for me. Try: import "style-loader!css-loader!./index.css"

Comment: This is just a workaround of the issue. The OP is looking for a solution that will help recognizing the css-loader by webpack.